# Qt. QString перевод в код ASCII

Tags: qt, char, ascii, qstring

Читал про toLocal8Bit().constData()...но не дошло.

Или подскажите как перевести QString в char.

Comment: в char не перевести, потому что строка - это массив символов. Что именно хочется?

Comment: Хочется QString перевести в ASCII код.

Получается нужно взять каждый символ и перевести его в int. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
  char c = s[i].toLatin1();
  // тут выводим символ с
  QDebug() << (int) c;
}
```